# Mongoose JS: Create a reference in one document to an embedded document in another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node / Mongoose / MongoDB and trying to build a polling application. A key need is to track how a single user's responses to the same poll changes over time (they take the same poll over and over).

I have a user model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ...
})
```

I'm embedding Questions in my poll documents because I'm almost always going to need the questions when I request a poll.

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: true }
})

var PollSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    questions: [QuestionSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', PollSchema);

// Know this is unnecessary, but read the following to see why I'm doing this
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

Here's my confusion:

My users will be taking the same poll multiple times. Accordingly, I'm creating an "AnswerHistory" which contains each "Answer" by a single user to a single question in a poll.

What I don't understand how to do is create a reference from one document to an embedded document in another document. For example:

```
var AnswerSchema = new Schema({
    answer: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: Date }
})

var AnswerHistorySchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    // I know this is wrong, but...
    question: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' },
    answers: [AnswerSchema]
})
```

What am I missing here?

- Do I need to reference the Poll instead, and keep track of which question the AnswerHistory applies to within the Poll?
- Or does this mean I shouldnt be embedding questions within the poll documents?
- Something else I'm not thinking of?

Edit: Here is a more concise way of looking at the problem:

```
var C = new Schema({...});
var B = new Schema({c: [C]});
var A = new Schema({c: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'B.c' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a history schema I'd rather to have 'versions' of the poll tracking the user and the answers.

every time that a user do a new poll you create a PollByUser object.

let's say:

```
 var PollByUserSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    poll:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll' },
    taken:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('PollByUser', PollByUserSchema);

var AnswerSchema = new Schema({
    answer: { type: String, required: true },
    time: { type: Date },
    question: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' },
    pollByUser: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'PollByUser' },

})
```

**EDIT:**

```
var PollSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    questions: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I see what you mean about the overall strategy, but I'm still a bit confused. My understanding is that I can't use ref: "Question" in the AnswerSchema because questions are embedded docs in Poll. Is that not true?

Comment: I got you, well at far I know you can't, but you can change your poll schema to only have questions id's as references

Comment: Hmm, that was the one thing I was trying to avoid. I'll accept the answer if no one suggests a way to avoid this. Thanks!